# Are there any estimates of military spending as a percentage of total government expenditure anywhere in 15th century Europe?

Tags: military, europe, economy, government, 15th-century

A little piece of information stuck in my head about the military expenditure. Namely, the current expenditure on the military is incredibly low when compared to that in the middle ages. I am not sure, but I think the source for this information might be this [Yuval Noah Harari's article](https://www.economist.com/by-invitation/2022/02/09/yuval-noah-harari-argues-that-whats-at-stake-in-ukraine-is-the-direction-of-human-history) (behind a paywall).

Indeed, [current average military expenditure in the EU seems very low](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1293562/expenditure-on-military-defense-as-gdp-share-in-the-european-union-eu-27/), at less than 2%.

I am interested in a very rough estimation of the expenditure on the military as a percentage of the total government expenditure (GDP appeared as a concept at the end of the 18th century, [source](https://www.worldometers.info/gdp/what-is-gdp/), so I cannot use this concept). **Something along the line of 20-40% would be fine because it clearly shows the discrepancy between now and then**

I have found [this article](https://eh.net/encyclopedia/military-spending-patterns-in-history/) that seems to provide some data related to what I am interested in:

> in republican and imperial Rome military wages accounted for **more than
> half of the revenue**

This is way back in time from my period of interest, but I will use this as a baseline estimation.

> The age of total war in the nineteenth and twentieth centuries finally
> pushed these states to adopt more and more efficient fiscal systems
> and e**nabled some of them to dedicate more than half of their GDP to
> the war effort during the world wars.**

I would filter out such major military events that clearly drag a lot of resources.

> The Dutch case also underlines the primacy of military spending in
> state budgets and the burden involved for the early modern states. The
> defense share of the Dutch region of Groningen remained consistently
> around 80 to 90 percent until the mid-seventeenth century, and then it
> declined, at least temporarily during periods of peace.

This shows the example of a rather small region, which spent at least 30% on military between 1596-and 1795. That's very close to the period of interest, but I am not sure if this example can scale to cover most of the regions in late Middle Age Europe.

[The same article](https://eh.net/encyclopedia/military-spending-patterns-in-history/) provides a modern example outside of major wars that shows way smaller values than above:

> Military Burdens of Four Great Powers and Aggregate Real Military
> Expenditure (ME) for Sixteen Countries on the Aggregate, 1870-1913

[image: Military Burdens of Four Great Powers and Aggregate Real Military Expenditure (ME) for Sixteen Countries on the Aggregate, 1870-1913]

I sense that the interval I am looking for should be somewhere between 20% and 40%, but I cannot find a source for it.

Anyway, all examples from above confirm the idea that we are currently living in times of very low expenditure on the military (as % of GDP).

Comment: Why do you believe a gross domestic product existed in the early modern?

Comment: One can at least estimate a revenue, in the cease of a centralized state with efficient bureaucracy (I cannot think of any example in the 15th century Europe). However, estimating GDP in a preindustrial society appears to me simply impossible.

Comment: @SamuelRussell True and I replaced it with something that could make sense back then.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I have replaced GDP with "government spending". Even if efficient bureaucracy did not exist, I guess there are some estimates for the local government / leadership income.

Comment: This recent [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/68579/what-is-the-price-of-modern-warfare-compared-to-medieval-in-terms-of-gdp#comment219802_68579) seems closely related.

Comment: You're looking at it from a wrong angle. Government expenditure was the personal expense of the monarch. William of Orange, for example, sold his private possessions, including his silver tableware, to pay for his troops. GPD simply didn't exist as yet.

Comment: I made an edit that would narrow the question down in a way that I feel would be sufficient to fit in the rules here, OP. Hopefully that should still serve your purposes (if you're expecting a full accounting of Europe in general, that is not within the realm of our records).

Comment: You will find estimates of military burden in governement/society reading quantitative-based military historians. See: Index of Country Power Military Capabilities, 1494-1945 (Brecke). This author is what you are looking for. Also, see economic historians like Seven Centuries of European Economic Growth and Decline (Fouquet, Broadberry, 2015), Portuguese Economic Growth, 1527-1850 (Palma, Reis, 2018), VAN ZANDEN, J. L. (2001). Early modern economic growth: a survey of the European economy, 1500–1800, and others.

Comment: I wonder if it might not be prudent to start with a question about "What were the segments of government spending in the era?"  I realize that the question has removed "GDP", but I think an accurate, meaningful answer rests on some kind of model of revenue/spending for the era.  I don't have evidence to hand, but I think that that model is going to be highly inconsistent; the revenue model in France will be different than England, and probably different in Germany and in Eastern Europe, etc. Will it vary by degree of autocracy? Sovereignty?

Comment: You are mixing up GDP and government expenditure the 2% figure is a percentage of GDP not government expenditure.

Comment: @MCW I think it is fair to say that the biggest and most important function of the crown was to create and pay the military. Since health care, social welfare, education, etc programs were much smaller scale than nowadays, most large infrastructural investments were military-related (fortresses, castles, bridges) the rest went mainly for the military. E.g Mathias Corivus (Hungary) had about 650 - 800 000 florins/year. The Black Army was about 30 000 soldiers, many of them getting 3-6 florins, which means that their payment itself was significant of the king's budget.